# What DLNA media server supports the most file formats?

Tags: media-server

What is the best DLNA server to use on an Raspberry Pi with support for the most file formats? I tried Logitech Media Server and MiniDLNA and both seem incapable of serving media in an AVI container.

Is this a problem of configuration or do I need a different DLNA server?

Previously, I used PS3 Media Server on a Mac, which worked fine, but as far as I know there is no working version for the Raspberry Pi (yet).

Comment: PS3 media server is written in Java, which is not yet well supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DLNA standard defines the supported file formats. If you need more file formats then you need a server that transcodes(decodes the unsupported format and encodes again in a supported format) the data. Transcoding in real time or for fast forward even faster is probably too much stress for the Raspberry Pi, at least for video, audio may work.

The Linux Version of PS3 Media Server could work. You need a ARM Java JRE (can be downloaded from oracle or Iced tea) and all external tools that are used (Mplayer,..) in ARM Linux versions.

Comment: Seems you are right. I now compiled the newest version of MiniDLNA and previously non-working files (mkv, avi) can now be played on my TV. I have no idea what the problem was, but it works now. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

MythTV is probably the best - http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/UPnP

> MythTV versions starting from 0.20 have a built-in UPnP server (a so called "UPnP AV MediaServer" device). UPnP servers are where you store and share your media (pictures/videos/audio/music) from. So you can share MythTV media files to any UPnP client (a so called "UPnP AV MediaServer ControlPoint" device) on your local-network, as long as the UPnP client is not behind a firewall or you have opened the ports for UPnP in your firewall. The UPnP client can then play those media files if it supports those MythTV codecs/container formats.